# set an iframe source without loading new content

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

Is there any way to set the src attribute of an iframe without the iframe generating an http request? If not, is there a way to format the request headers before the request is sent?

edit: I just need the src to match the path of a cookie, but I don't ever want that cookie sent to the server. See my comments on this question.

Comment: I'm curious exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to use cookies to store some data that's global to the browser but never send that data to the server. If the cookie path is /somepath and the iframe src is /somepath and the iframe never sends the cookie to the server, problem solved.

Comment: I want this feature but don't want to wait for the HTML 5 storage API.

Comment: Also see the question 'use cookies without sending them back to the server'. http://tiny.cc/X7dkt

Comment: Can you have it load a real page, thats just a static html file (blank.html) and just never send that page back to the server? Another idea is to use the page loaded in the iframe to have the script that sets the cookies since it knows its own url.

Comment: If the page reloads, the iframe reloads and the cookie is sent to the server. The thought is if I load a new page with the iframe pointing to /path, and the iframe doesn't make a roundtrip, then I have access to any cookie with path=/path. The cookie could have been created at any time.

Comment: Would it be ok if the iframe loading only once (before the cookie was set)? you could set the source via javascript and only set it if your cookie does not exist. I dont know, this all sounds crazy to me at this point.

Comment: lol. Yup, it's crazy. I just wanted to go all the way down this path before I was comfortable saying it can't be done. I have officially given up. :-) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

No there is not a way to do this.